# What's the meaning of "a bleak shadow of"?

Tags: meaning

What's the meaning of "a bleak shadow of"?

> Even the landscape of their resettlement proved **a bleak shadow of** West Bank terrain: “Those who fled from the West Bank left behind them fertile areas for the semi- desert plains of the East Bank”

Comment: *a bleak shadow* means having little or no hope.

Comment: @MaulikV I think *shadow* is a metaphor here.  I think there are three things you need to understand it: 1. read the sentence as though "to be" is omitted after "proved"; 2. look at the following phrase (*of West Bank terrain*); 3. read the following sentence, as well.

Answer (score 1):

When one thing is a *shadow* of another, it's something that is similar but inferior.

> After his illness, the ball-player was a shadow of his former self.

In your example, they're saying that the landscape of the East Bank is inferior to the landscape of the West Bank.

*Bleak* is just being used in it's usual meaning, "barren, desolate". It is saying why one area is inferior to the other.